# How do I register 'Scene' properties with Python in 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I'm currently udpating some 2.7x script for 2.8. Everything is going fine except for one thing:

Currently the script uses a class to store some properties like so:

```
class MySettings(PropertyGroup):
    lockHead = BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="Lock the head position of the bone",
        default = False
        )
```

which is registered in the registration part:

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
```

The issue is, Blender 2.8 doesn't want to register it in the `Scene`. I try to register it in the `Window` like so :

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Window.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Window.my_tool
```

But then I can't get the property elsewhere (if I get it with `context.window.my_tool` I just have some weird tuple and can't reach the property itself). Here's an example where I try to get them in a separate  UI class:

```
def draw (self, context):
                   
    layout = self.layout
        
    mytool = context.window.my_tool
        
    rows = 2
    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.prop(mytool, "lockHead",  icon='NDOF_DOM', text="Head")
```

So the question is, where can I register the `PropertyGroup` class so I can access the properties inside in an other class? Or am I doing something commpletly wrong?

And side question, since the classes are no longer stored in the `bpy.types` "class", how can I get them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Annotations in 2.80**

Not sure of the problem here. 2.8 uses [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), currently not doing so produces a warning message.

*Test code to confirm operation in 2.80*

```
import bpy

class MySettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    # use an annotation
    lockHead : bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="Lock the head position of the bone",
        default=False
        )

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    print(bpy.context.scene.my_tool.lockHead)
```

Test in console:

```
>> C.scene.my_tool
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].my_tool

>>> C.scene.my_tool.lockHead
False

>>> C.scene.my_tool.lockHead = True
>>> C.scene.my_tool.lockHead
True
```

Trying on `bpy.types.Window` is an issue. The use of `bpy.props` is restricted to `ID` types.  As a rule of thumb  objects in the `bpy.data` collections are `ID` type..  `Scene` type in `bpy.data.scenes`.  There is no `bpy.data.windows` for the `Window` type.  (there is the window manager)

```
>>> isinstance(C.window, bpy.types.ID)
False

>>> isinstance(C.window_manager, bpy.types.ID)
True

>>> bpy.types.WindowManager.my_tool = bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
>>> C.window_manager.my_tool.lockHead
False
```

Only a rule of thumb test, as shown by a pose bone.

```
>>> bpy.types.PoseBone.my_tool = bpy.types.Scene.my_tool
>>> C.active_pose_bone
bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["Bone"]

>>> C.active_pose_bone.my_tool.lockHead
False

>>> isinstance(C.active_pose_bone, bpy.types.ID)
False
```

A more robust test, If a blender object doesn't support ID properties, it cannot be used to store custom properties defined with `bpy.props`

```
>>> C.window["x"] = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct[key] = val: id properties not supported for this type
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very complete answer, I understand a bit better the different types now. The code you gave works well and I found, by comparing, a typo in my code that was at fault... Thanks again everything works fine now ! So if somebody comes one day here, don't forget the () in `register()` :D

Answer (score 0):

An important part of using `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` class, is you have to register it before you use a `bpy.props.PointerProperty` on it.
I prefer to register it right after creation:

```
class MySettings(PropertyGroup):
    prop = BoolProperty()
bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
MySettings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)
    # bpy.types.Scene.MySettings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)
...
```

You could essentially place that under the `AddonPreferences` class, to create prop groups there or even inside an `Operator` class.
The only reason I can think of where you MUST place anything in `register()` would be if you wanted to run the commands after the `.py` file is loaded *(to maintain the commonly used "`register`" name)*.

Comment: It's a matter of good practice vs personal preference. The modules `register()` method is called when as an  addon it is enabled, and `unregister()` when it is disabled.  The idea is to have the addons registered types available when the addon is enabled, and clean up when it is disabled.  If put outside as suggested above they will be registered  for instance when the app imports the addon as a fake module  to investigate its `bl_info` dictionary for  addons list in prefs.  Also please look to the question where it specifies the 2.8 version where annotations are used.