# Hear timing reference audio from VSE while editing other scenes? (2.8 beta)

Tags: video-sequence-editor, scene, audio

I'm making an animation using grease pencil, based on a narration track. What I'd like to do:

1. Import and place the master audio file (narration) as a single sound
   strip in the VSE, in Scene0
2. Create visuals as grease pencil scenes sequenced in the VSE too, from which a final export can be made. Scene1 - Scene50.
3. I want to use the narration track in the VSE in Scene0 as a timing reference for all visuals in all scenes of the project. e.g. in Scene3 I want a specific action to coincide with a particular word in the narration. In general **while working on the action in Scene N I want to hear the relevant part of the narration audio which has been placed in the VSE in Scene0, a different scene**.

I have a good handle on 1 and 2, but I'm not sure how to realise 3. Is it possible?

Suggestions for workarounds or alternative approaches are welcome too. Though I'd like to avoid any workaround that involves having to re-render audio files if the duration of any of the grease pencil scenes has to change.

EDIT

In After effects there's a plugin called 'universal audio' that achieves something similar to what I'm looking for in Blender: It provides some buttons that allow you to designate a 'master audio' track, and then from child comps automatically copy in the appropriate section of audio from the master audio track, with in point correctly reflecting its position with regard to how the two comps are related. https://aescripts.com/universal-audio/

EDIT 2

I think that if I make sure I use the Scene name 'Master' for the one containing the VSE and name the narration sound clip 'Narration', then I'd need something like the following script (i'd run this somehow each time I opened one of the scenes to work on). But I'm not clear yet on how to have this accessible via a button or something convenient.

```
# Run this from a 'child' scene to add narration track with correct timing offset.
# TODO add routine for removing narration track from child scene if it already exists, before re-adding it.

    import bpy

    current_scene = bpy.context.scene
    current_se = current_scene.sequence_editor_create()

    master_se = bpy.data.scenes['Master'].sequence_editor
    narration_sequence = master_se.sequences['Narration']

    timing_ref_sequence = master_se.sequences[current_scene.name] 

    if timing_ref_sequence:
      offset = timing_ref_sequence.frame_final_start * -1
      path = narration_sequence.sound.filepath
      current_se.sequences.new_sound('new',path,0,offset)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've reworded parts of the question and added emphasis. I hope that helps make it clearer.

Comment: Lets say master audio is in scene "MasterAudio" a master audio strip added to all other scenes with drivers on props from original would do the trick?  Be an easy enough script.  _Coincidentally playing around with integrating audacity ... blendaucity_

Comment: @batFINGER If i'm understanding correctly a script like that would be a big help. Are you thinking that the 'MasterAudio' scene would have a VSE in which all other scenes were placed, and the script would use the start positions of the scenes in the VSE to automatically add and adjust the start position of the audio strip in those 'child' scenes?

Comment: I commend your efforts and time invested in your research. I have modified the python script, which you have started. @ alert me in a comment, if some parts of the code are unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the python script conveniently accessible, we have to embed it into an [addon](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) for [2.8](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons).

To activate the addon for this file only, copy the code (at the end of the post) and save it in a file (e.g. `adjustNarratorTrack.py`). Open it in the script editor in Blender and check the **Register** checkbox in the header of the script editor. With *register* enabled, a **saved** file will be automatically executed once the blend file is loaded, even if you close the script editor.

To run the script, without reloading the blend file, click <kbd>Run</kbd><kbd>Script</kbd>.

The script creates a python [operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operator#bpy.types.Operator). The operator can be called by

- opening the search menu in the *3D View* <kbd>F3</kbd> and typing `Adjust Narrator`
- clicking on the menu item, which we created under `3D View ▶ Object ▶ Adjust Narrator Track`

[image: call operator]

<sub>Note, that this "addon" is not quite complete yet. Further research should be done as to how scene/sound strips behave, when they are *cut off* in the sequencer.</sub>

In the script

- a custom Operator `AdjustNarratorTrackOperator` is defined. This will be called by Blender when you click on the menu items. It will be also available to python through `bpy.ops.`.
- two [annotations](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127500/30849) of the operator are defined: `audio_strip_name`, `cut_scene_name`. These are adjustable after the operator has been executed. This is useful if you have changed your naming conventions.
  [image: operator annotation]
  <sup>*The operator annotations appear in the 3D View after the operator has been executed.*</sup>
- there are two methods:

  1. `execute`: called by Blender
  2. `adjust_audio_reference`: a modified version of your script
- In `adjust_audio_reference` the `current_scene`, `audio_strip_name` and `cut_scene_name` are referenced from the operators context.
  Various checks are done to ensure, that

  1. the "Master" scene exists
  2. the "Master" scene contains the audio track
  3. the current scene is not the "Master" scene
  4. the current scene is contained as a strip in the "Master" scene
  5. the sound strip is replicated in the current scene if necessary
  6. the offset in timing is applied

In this case we want to use the `frame_start` property and not the `frame_start_final` property, since the frame offset to the frame_start_final doesn't reflect on the audio strips position at the start of a scene strip.

```
import bpy


class AdjustNarratorTrackOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Adjusts the narrator track"""
    bl_idname = "object.adjust_narrator_track"
    bl_label = "Adjust Narrator Track"

    audio_strip_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(default='Narration')
    cut_scene_name: bpy.props.StringProperty(default='Master')

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            self.adjust_audio_reference()
        except Exception as e:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, str(e))
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def adjust_audio_reference(self):
        current_scene = bpy.context.scene
        audio_strip_name = self.audio_strip_name
        cut_scene_name = self.cut_scene_name

        # check if the master scene exists and contains the audio_strip
        master_scn = bpy.data.scenes.get(cut_scene_name)
        if master_scn == None or master_scn.sequence_editor == None:
            raise Exception('Master scene not defined.')
        master_se = master_scn.sequence_editor
        ref_audio_strip = master_se.sequences.get(audio_strip_name)
        print(ref_audio_strip)
        if ref_audio_strip == None or ref_audio_strip.type != 'SOUND':
            raise Exception('Audio strip not found.')


        # check if the current scene is embedded in the master scene
        timing_ref_seqs = [s for s in master_se.sequences if s.type == 'SCENE' and s.scene == current_scene]
        if len(timing_ref_seqs) == 0:
            raise Exception('Current scene is not contained in the Master scene.')

        ref_scn_strip = timing_ref_seqs[0]


        current_se = current_scene.sequence_editor
        if current_se == None:
            current_se = current_scene.sequence_editor_create()
        current_audio_strip = current_se.sequences.get(ref_audio_strip.name)
        if current_audio_strip != None:
            if current_audio_strip.type != 'SOUND':
                current_audio_strip.name = current_audio_strip.name + '_notSound'
                current_audio_strip = None
        if current_audio_strip == None:
            path = ref_audio_strip.sound.filepath
            current_audio_strip = current_se.sequences.new_sound(ref_audio_strip.name,path,0,0)

        timing_difference = ref_audio_strip.frame_start - ref_scn_strip.frame_start + current_scene.frame_start

        current_audio_strip.frame_start = timing_difference
        current_audio_strip.frame_final_start = timing_difference

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(AdjustNarratorTrackOperator.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AdjustNarratorTrackOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AdjustNarratorTrackOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thanks. Though this doesn't get at what I'm hoping for. While I'm working on Scene1 I want to be able to hear audio that I've placed in the VSE in Scene0 (Scene1 is also placed in that same VSE).

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment above this is what I had in mind

Set up a master audio scene. All it has is audio in the sequencer, no camera nothing else. For process of example I have called this scene "MasterAudio".

[image]
*MasterAudio Scene*

Placing this scene as a strip in any other VSE and we can hear the audio. All that is left is to align them.

The soft trim is animatable. I have added a couple of simple drivers to trim the master audio scene strip to match the context scene.  This is a bit dodgy as it doesn't seem to update that well, and has the tendency to set the scene strips frame start.

[image]
*Result of running on empty scene*

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
master_audio_scene_name = "MasterAudio"


def add_master_audio_scene(scene):
    sed = scene.sequence_editor or scene.sequence_editor_create()
    ma_scene = bpy.data.scenes.get(master_audio_scene_name)
    mas = sed.sequences.new_scene(
            master_audio_scene_name,
            ma_scene,
            1,
            ma_scene.frame_start)
    # only use sed of mas
    mas.frame_start = scene.frame_start
    mas.frame_final_duration = scene.frame_end - scene.frame_start
    mas.use_sequence = True

    # drivers         
    fcurve = mas.driver_add("frame_offset_start")
    driver = fcurve.driver
    var = driver.variables.new()
    var.name = "fs"
    #var.id_data = scene
    var.targets[0].id_type = 'SCENE'
    var.targets[0].id = scene
    var.targets[0].data_path = "frame_start"

    var = driver.variables.new()
    var.name = "mfs"
    var.targets[0].id_type = 'SCENE'
    var.targets[0].id = ma_scene
    var.targets[0].data_path = "frame_start"


    driver.expression = "max(0, fs - mfs)"
    fcurve = mas.driver_add("frame_offset_end")
    driver = fcurve.driver
    var = driver.variables.new()
    var.name = "fe"
    var.targets[0].id_type = 'SCENE'
    var.targets[0].id = scene
    var.targets[0].data_path = "frame_end"

    var = driver.variables.new()
    var.name = "mfe"
    var.targets[0].id_type = 'SCENE'
    var.targets[0].id = ma_scene
    var.targets[0].data_path = "frame_end"

    driver.expression = "max(0, mfe -fe)"


    # drivers

scene = context.scene
add_master_audio_scene(scene)
```

Answer (score -1):

Cut your audio e.g with Audacity and , in Blender 3D view, put a Speaker object to hear your audio bit. When you go to the next frame, insert respective audio bit and so on.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.