# Blender Python: Declare Property Group (on the stack?)

Tags: python, development

The questions keep coming, I know. I cannot find this simple answer anywhere. It may be because I'm not sure exactly how to phrase it in searches.

Is it possible to declare a variable of a custom type that is derived from `bpy.types.PropertyGroup`?

I have a situation where I create controls for the active object. But I would like to show these controls in a disabled state when there is no active object (or any object at all). So my (possibly terrible) idea is to declare a local variable of the property group used by objects and use the data in this temporary property group to draw the buttons and controls. I know I can just skip drawing the associated controls, but I don't like how disruptive it is to have the panel contents shift around when it happens.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
class MyClass(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    Var : BoolProperty(
        name = "Stuff",
        description = "my stuff",
        default=False
        )

def draw_panel():

    if active_object:
        draw_buttons(active_object.MyProperties, disabled=false)
    else:
        temp_props = MyClass()
        draw_buttons(temp_props, disabled=true)
```

So the controls would be associated with a temporary property object. However, the code `temp_props = MyClass()` does not work. It appears that `bpy_struct` requires some type of "constructor parameter" (I'm not sure what these are called in python)?

If there is a better way to handle this, please feel free to slap me out of this idea. And in either case, how would one go about declaring a class derived from a property group or `bpy_struct` locally within a function? Is it even possible? I can't seem to find anything in the API docs about initializing one of these objects on our own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to accomplish this is to set up a `PointerProperty` on the scene to store these values:

```py
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyClass)
    bpy.types.Scene.temp_props = PointerProperty(type=MyClass)
```

Now you can reference the properties in your `draw_buttons` call with `bpy.context.scene.temp_props`:

```py
def draw_panel():

    if active_object:
        draw_buttons(active_object.MyProperties, disabled=False)
    else:
        temp_props = bpy.context.scene.temp_props
        draw_buttons(temp_props, disabled=True)
```

You can also store the `PointerProperty` to many other ID structs from `bpy.types` (e.g. `Object`, `World`, `ViewLayer`, etc.).

(related: [How do I register 'Scene' properties with Python in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127462/how-do-i-register-scene-properties-with-python-in-2-8))

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Can anyone help me understand why it works to add my custom property groups to blender objects (objects, scene), but I get errors when I try to add them to my own structures (eg, Panel.TempObjectProperties)? The environment complains when I try to use a property inside prop_enum() when the property group is owned by the panel. It reports "Function.data expected a AnyType type, not tuple". Is Blender doing something additional to initialize these behind the scenes? Or are property groups exclusively designed for object association?