# How to get operator object from id?

Tags: scripting

I'm writing a script that contains both an operator and a panel.  Both the operator and the panel are created in the script's `register()` method.  In my panel's `draw()` method, I'd like to be able to get a reference to the operator object so I can access its properties.  Is there a way to look up the operator object using its ID?

--- Edit

To elaborate on the above - I'm trying to create an object picker field.  The idea is that I have a string field called 'target'.  I want my `NormalToolPropsPanel` panel to display a string field representing the `target` field of my operator.  Then when the user clicks on the eyedropper icon, they can pick an object in the scene and its name will be filled into the field.

```
class ModalDrawOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Adjust normals"""
    bl_idname = "kitfox.normal_tool"
    bl_label = "Normal Tool Kitfox"


    prop_brush_type : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=(
            ('FIXED', "Fixed", "Normals are in a fixed direction"),
            ('ATTRACT', "Attract", "Normals point toward target object"),
            ('REPEL', "Repel", "Normals point away from target object")
        ),
        default='FIXED'
    )
    
    prop_strength : bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Strength", description="Amount to adjust mesh normal", default = 1, min=0, max = 1
    )

    prop_normal = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(name="Normal", description="Direction of normal in Fixed mode", default = (0, 1, 0))
    prop_target = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Target", description="Object Attract and Repel mode reference", default="")
    

    def mouse_down(self, context, event):
        #Do the work here
        pass

    def modal(self, context, event):
        context.area.tag_redraw()

        if event.type in {'MIDDLEMOUSE', 'WHEELUPMOUSE', 'WHEELDOWNMOUSE'}:
            # allow navigation
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        elif event.type == 'MOUSEMOVE':
            pass
        elif event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            self.mouse_down(context, event)
            pass

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            print("norm tool cancelled")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._context = context
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

            self.mouse_path = []

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

#------------------------

class NTTargetPickerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Pick object with the mouse"""
    bl_idname = "kitfox.nt_pick_target_object"
    bl_label = "Normal Tool Pick Target Object Kitfox"

    def mouse_down(self, context, event):
        mouse_pos = (event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y)

        ctx = bpy.context

        region = context.region
        rv3d = context.region_data
        view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, mouse_pos)
        ray_origin = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, mouse_pos)

        viewlayer = bpy.context.view_layer
        result, location, normal, index, object, matrix = context.scene.ray_cast(viewlayer.depsgraph, ray_origin, view_vector)
        
        if result:
            print("--picked " + object.name)

            #This doesn't work - I want to set the property 'target' on my operator
            bpy.ops.kitfox.normal_tool["prop_target.set"] = object.name
            

    def modal(self, context, event):

        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            self.mouse_down(context, event)
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
            print("pick target object cancelled")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        else:
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            # the arguments we pass the the callback
            args = (self, context)
            # Add the region OpenGL drawing callback
            # draw in view space with 'POST_VIEW' and 'PRE_VIEW'
            self._context = context
            self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback, args, 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "View3D not found, cannot run operator")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

#------------------------

class NormalToolPropsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):

    """Properties Panel for the Normal Tool on tool shelf"""
    bl_label = "Normal Tool Properties Panel"
    bl_idname = "3D_VIEW_PT_normal_tool_props"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

        

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        props = layout.operator(ModalDrawOperator.bl_idname)

        row = layout.row()

        #Not working - I want to refer to the property in my operator
        row.prop(bpy.ops.kitfox.normal_tool, "prop_target", expand=True)

        pickOp = layout.operator(NTTargetPickerOperator.bl_idname, icon="EYEDROPPER")

#------------------------


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NTTargetPickerOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NormalToolPropsPanel)



def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NTTargetPickerOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalDrawOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NormalToolPropsPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203747/addon-how-to-make-blender-run-check-redraw-when-option-changed  or look at the code of a number of importers in recent versions, where it has become common to use a panel referencing `context.active_operator`

Comment: I looked at the linked comment, but saw nothing about looking up an operator by id.  Also, the operator will not necessarily be the active operator.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're trying to do with your script (what it's for)?, are you trying to imitate functionality you saw in blender?

Comment: Please add some detail and clarity to question. In a panel draw method `props = self.layout.operator("foo.bar")` is a reference to its properties, which can be set in draw method with `props.prop = 33` , trying to use `layout.prop(props, "prop")` however will not work. (Given your since deleted answer) Please elaborate on what is the expectation here.

Comment: Thankyou for the edits. [Only ID (and bones) objects can have custom properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127500/15543). ID objects have `bpy.types.ID` as a subclass. An operator `bpy.types.Operator` is not an ID object.    AFAICT this could be replaced by having a "kitfox tools" property group with the target object as a pointer property to `bpy.types.Object` which can be set via eyedropper see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159155/15543

Comment: I made some revisions, but it's still not working.  I've posted a new question which makes progress on what I posted above:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209199/how-to-get-panel-to-use-properties-from-a-propertygroup

Comment: Ok going around in circles a bit here. Have used other one I closed to demo what I mean re pointer property here.  Took out the operator, but as mentioned prior if I run the code with reference to `ModalOperator` or some class I havent defined and use `layout.operator(ModalOperator.bl_idname)` it will run and register without error, however it will start spitting errors to the console as soon as I try and see the panel. and the panel will show no more after any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Make a settings group and use a pointer property for target object**

[image]

With regard to edit

> To elaborate on the above - I'm trying to create an object picker
> field. The idea is that I have a string field called 'target'. I want
> my NormalToolPropsPanel panel to display a string field representing
> the target field of my operator. Then when the user clicks on the
> eyedropper icon, they can pick an object in the scene and its name
> will be filled into the field.

as commented feel this is better done with a pointer property.

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras import view3d_utils


class NormalToolSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    brush_type : bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        items=(
            ('FIXED', "Fixed", "Normals are in a fixed direction"),
            ('ATTRACT', "Attract", "Normals point toward target object"),
            ('REPEL', "Repel", "Normals point away from target object")
        ),
        default='FIXED'
    )
    
    strength : bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="Strength", description="Amount to adjust mesh normal", default = 1, min=0, max = 1
    )

    normal : bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(name="Normal", description="Direction of normal in Fixed mode", default = (0, 1, 0))
    target : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
        

#---------------------------

class NormalToolPropsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):

    """Properties Panel for the Normal Tool on tool shelf"""
    bl_label = "Normal Tool Properties Panel"
    bl_idname = "VIEW3D_PT_normal_tool_props"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "KitFox"
        

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        settings = scene.my_tool

        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(settings, "strength")
        col.prop(settings, "brush_type")
        col.prop(settings, "normal")
        col.prop(settings, "target")                       
#---------------------------


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NormalToolSettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NormalToolPropsPanel)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=NormalToolSettings)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NormalToolSettings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NormalToolPropsPanel)
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you wish to set this to something else in modal then when you know the object

```
context.scene.my_tool.target = hit_object
```

and it will update in the UI.

Tip: Look at the subtypes of `FloatVectorProperty` for other options to keep the value normalized.