# Adding properties to bpy.types.Fcurve (monkey patching)

Tags: python, add-on, dopesheet, fcurves

I'm trying to add a pointer property to the FCurve type, which has to point to a specific GPencilLayer type.

So far, here's what i tried without success :

i firstly tried to add a single attribute to the FCurve type :

```
bpy.types.FCurve.layer = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.GPencilLayer
```

but while assigning a GPencilLayer to it i have :

```
AttributeError: 'FCurve' object attribute 'layer2' is read-only
```

So i tried to use a property group :

```
class DS_TARGET(PropertyGroup):
    bl_label = "gp dopesheet targets"
    bl_idname = "ds.target"   
    layer : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.GPencilLayer)
```

but this classe won't register because of the "layer" property so i think i will use list then append / pop the GPLayer in it :

```
class DS_TARGET(PropertyGroup):
    bl_label = "gp dopesheet targets"
    bl_idname = "ds.target"   
    layer = []
```

While trying to add the target attribute to my FCurve type i tried :

```
bpy.types.FCurve.target = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=DS_TARGET)
```

But this will result in a read-only thing and i can't even access my .layer attribute :

```
<_PropertyDeferred, <built-in function PointerProperty>, {'type': <class 'GP_Dopesheets.DS_TARGET'>}>
```

This logic used to work with other types like Scene or Object, but not for Fcurves ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hello ! Don't quote me on that : Only classes deriving from type [ID](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID), bones and armatures can accept custom properties. [Fcurve](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurve.html) doesn't so you can't add custom properties to it globally.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i was afraid of... i should try something else..

Comment: ... one workaround could be to add a collection property to the action, which is an ID type.  Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127500/15543

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Emulate the fcurves collection.**

Can only assign `bpy.props` to `ID` types and bones. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127500/15543

As a workaround could add a collection property to the action, which is an ID type.

A simple setup, with a propertygroup having a `data_path` and `array_index` property just like an fcurve. The matching fcurve is returned via a regular python property.

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import CollectionProperty,  StringProperty, IntProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup, Action

class GPFcurve(PropertyGroup):
    data_path: StringProperty()
    array_index: IntProperty()
    @property
    def fcurve(self):
        return self.id_data.fcurves.find(self.data_path, index=self.array_index)
bpy.utils.register_class(GPFcurve)
Action.gpfcurves = CollectionProperty(type=GPFcurve)
```

Test and populate in the python console.

```
>>> action = D.actions['CubeAction']
>>> gpfcurves = action.gpfcurves
>>> for fc in action.fcurves:
...     gpfc = gpfcurves.add()
...     gpfc.data_path = fc.data_path
...     gpfc.array_index = fc.array_index
...     gpfc.fcurve
...     
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction']...FCurve
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction']...FCurve
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction']...FCurve
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction']...FCurve
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction']...FCurve
```

Ok now have a collection that "somewhat mirrors" the fcurve collection for this action.  Add other properties to group to point the item to the grease pencil type.