# Can't get invoke_props_dialog to render any props for operator

Tags: python, interface

this is taken from an example and it seems to be about as simple as one could get. I have tried on blender 3.4 and blender 3.5 and cannot get any of the properties to render. I've stared at this thinking I must have done something different than the example but it's exactly the same. When I run this I get the dialog but it only has the title and an OK button, there is no input for the "text" property.

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_TestUI(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Testing UI"
    bl_idname = "wm.testui"
    
    text = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Enter Text: ",default="")
    testint = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Enter a Number")
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_TestUI)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_TestUI)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

bpy.ops.wm.testui('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I register 'Scene' properties with Python in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127462/how-do-i-register-scene-properties-with-python-in-2-8)

Comment: Hello, for future reference, please post your code as text rather than an image, it's easier for others to debug. Cheers

Comment: Hi. Please don't post images or screenshots of your code, console or error messages, instead copy-paste the actual text into your post using proper code tags, so it can be indexed and searched for, and other users trying to help don't have to type it by hand themselves which is error prone and time consuming.

Comment: I edited and pasted the code. I was on my mobile device and only had the screenshot available when I originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `=` use `:` to define properties.

e.g. `text : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Enter Text: ",default="")` etc.

[image]

```
import bpy


class WM_OT_TestUI(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Testing UI"
    bl_idname = "wm.testui"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    text : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Enter Text: ",default="")
    testint : bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Enter a Number")
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
   

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_TestUI)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_TestUI)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.testui("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
```